# Sending AMPScript Variables to a Landing Page from Mobile Push

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, mobilepush, landing-page

We're trying to send some variables to our landing page that are set within AMPScript through a Mobile Push.

Within the setup of that Mobile Push (in the Alert Message), we have something along the lines of-

```
Hey, click on this notification!
%%[
SET @SubKey = 'John Doe'
SET @OffID = '123'
]%%
```

Obviously, the customer would only see "Hey, click on this notification!" Additionally, we wouldn't be hard coding the AMPScript variables (So John Doe would be Dynamic and so would the 123)

We also have the Mobile Push configured to send the customer to our landing page when they click on the notification.

The AMPScript on the landing page would then pick up this customer data using the QueryParameter() function and looks something like this-

```
SET @SubKey = QueryParameter('SubKey')
SET @OffID = QueryParameter('OffID')
```

This would then be used for the remainder of the landing page.

For email sends, we've used an HTML  tag like this-

```
href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123, 'SubKey', @SubKey, 'OffID', @OffID))=%%"
```

Mobile Push won't accept HTML, however. How can we pass on this information from the Mobile Push to our Cloud Page?

Comment: Have you tried the attributevalue or requestparameter AMPscript functions instead of queryparameter?

Comment: Thanks for the input, Adam! I was actually able to track down a solution. See my answer post below.

Comment: It's not a good idea to pass subscriber keys in plain text in the URL.  I'd try retrieving the values using AttributeValue.  CloudPagesURL parameters are encrypted in the QS value and retrievable using this function.

Comment: Good to know, thanks Adam! I'll make sure and give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you append AMPScript variables as URI parameters, they will then pass through to the Landing Page-

```
www.page.com/?SubKey=%%=v(@SubKey)=%%&OffID=%%=v(@OffID)=%%
```